# How do I Shift the waves by 45 degree, invert the cos waves. Subtract sine with cosine waves to plot the resultant wave

Tags: python, anaconda

Here is my code, I am able to invert sin graph but not cos graph

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
  
x = np.arange(0, 2*(np.pi), 0.1)
y = np.sin(-x)
z = np.cos(x)
  
plt.plot(x, y ,x , z)
plt.show()"
```

Comment: Can you indicate why you cannot invert cos? Do you get an error message? An unexpected result? Can you show what you have tried in that direction?